# Change Navbar Header Color on Resize

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm very new to front-end coding. I'm creating my own responsive website using Bootstrap 3.

When I resize my browser window to simulate the size of a phone screen, I want the nav bar color (nav header color?) to change to white on Menu Icon click.

I want it to stay transparent on page load and that is working. I want the header to change to white while scrolling and that is also working. When the hamburger menu icon is clicked, the collapsible nav header drops down to reveal the menu items, but the background remains transparent, causing the menu items to lay on top of the content below.

I wrote the following script but it doesn't seem to work. Does anyone have suggestions?

```
<script>
    var windowsize = $(window).width();
    $(window).resize(funtion() {
        windowsize = $(window).width();
            if (windowsize < 440) {
                $("#myNavbar").click(function () {
                  $(".navbar-header").css({"background-color": "#ffffff", "-webkit-box-shadow": "0px 1px 4px 0px rgba(180, 180, 180, 0.5)", "-moz-box-shadow": "0px 1px 4px 0px rgba(180,180,180, 0.5)", "box-shadow": "0px 1px 4px 0px rgba(180,180,180, 0.5)"});
                });
            };
      });
</script>
```

Comment: Do not put an event in an event.

Comment: A media query wouldn't solve his requirement of  `I want the nav bar color to change to white on Menu Icon click.`

Comment: You're missing a "c" in "function" for your `.resize()` call... is that how it is in your original script, or is that just a typo here?

Comment: Good catch! It is a typo in the original.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Media Queries](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_mediaqueries_ex.asp) in your CSS file for what you need.

```
@media screen and (max-width: 300px) {
    nav {
        background-color: #ffffff;
    }
}
```

Comment: Spent 1 hour looking for your answer. Thank You

Answer (score 1):

Since you are only changing the color on click, you don't need a window.resize() event.

```
<script>
    $("#myNavbar").click(function () {
        windowsize = $(window).width();

        if (windowsize < 440) {
            $(".navbar-header").css({"background-color": "#ffffff", "-webkit-box-shadow": "0px 1px 4px 0px rgba(180, 180, 180, 0.5)", "-moz-box-shadow": "0px 1px 4px 0px rgba(180,180,180, 0.5)", "box-shadow": "0px 1px 4px 0px rgba(180,180,180, 0.5)"});
        }
    });

</script>
```

I would suggest changing the dynamic CSS to use a class though too. The JS would change to `$(".navbar-header").addClass("active");` and you can define the active class in your css files.

Comment: I solved the issue, taking inputs from all answers. Took your suggestion on using a custom CSS class. Thank you. But I still needed to add and remove classes.

Answer (score 0):

Roughly like this, on click when res is less than 440 the navbar will be white :-

```js
<script>
      $('.navbar').click(function() {
           $(this).toggleClass('open');
      });
</script>
```

```css
@media only screen and (max-width: 440px) {
    .navbar.open {
      background-color: #ffffff;
      -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 1px 4px 0px rgba(180, 180, 180, 0.5);
      -moz-box-shadow: 0px 1px 4px 0px rgba(180,180,180, 0.5);
      box-shadow: 0px 1px 4px 0px rgba(180,180,180, 0.5);
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="navbar"></div>
```

Comment: Actually the toggleClass worked better. Thank you for your inputs.

Comment: Good point @Bhuvana - I have updated my answer. Glad you got it working :)

Answer (score 0):

Using media queries is the best way to make a css property dependent on the screen size.

Here is some code that might suit your needs:

```
.nav-bar {
    @media only screen and (max-width: 420px) {background:#fff;}
}
```

This makes the nav-bar white if the screen width is 420px or less.

Comment: Solved the issue. Its not just the header color, I needed to change the collapsible menu background as well. So I used the same logic I used for header color. Capturing the click function of the collapsible nav bar and toggling the colors. Here is my final piece of code:  <script>
  $(function (){
    $(".navbar-toggle").click(function() {
     if ($(window).width() < 440) {
      $(".navbar-collapse").toggleClass("menuActive");
      $(".navbar-header").toggleClass("menuActive");
     } 

    });
   }); 
</script>

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```js
$("#myNavbar").click(function () {
  $(".navbar-header").addClass("navbar-header-mobile");
});
```

```css
/* Extra Small Devices, Phones */ 
    @media only screen and (min-width : 480px) {
      .navbar-header-mobile {
        background-color: #ffffff;
        -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 1px 4px 0px rgba(180, 180, 180, 0.5);
        -moz-box-shadow: 0px 1px 4px 0px rgba(180,180,180, 0.5);
        box-shadow: 0px 1px 4px 0px rgba(180,180,180, 0.5);
      }
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

You just need to add something that removes it on the phone if you want.

Answer (score 0):

I'd do this via a class toggle in JS and a CSS media query.

JS -

```
$("#myNavbar").click(function() {
    $(".navbar-header").toggleClass('.active-nav')
});
```

CSS -

```
@media only screen and (min-width:440px) {
    .navbar-header.active-nav {
        background-color: #ffffff;
        -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 1px 4px 0px rgba(180, 180, 180, 0.5);
        -moz-box-shadow: 0px 1px 4px 0px rgba(180, 180, 180, 0.5);
        box-shadow: 0px 1px 4px 0px rgba(180, 180, 180, 0.5);
    }
}
```

Comment: The toggleClass was an awesome suggestion! I used that to make it work. But I did not use @media only..Just (window).width().

Answer (score 0):

Solved the issue. Its not just the header color, I needed to change the collapsible menu background as well. So I used the same logic I used for header color. Capturing the click function of the collapsible nav bar and toggling the colors. Here is my final piece of code:

```
<script>
  $(function (){
    $(".navbar-toggle").click(function() {
        if ($(window).width() < 440) {
            $(".navbar-collapse").toggleClass("menuActive");
            $(".navbar-header").toggleClass("menuActive");
        } 

    });
   }); 
</script>
```